# Travel to Portugal

Tags: usa, international-travel, covid-19, portugal

I'm looking to travel to Portugal either in July or August. What is the current plan to open back up for tourism. I've read around the 15th of June. Due to Portugal starting phase 3 reopening. Just trying to get good info, the us website isn't any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

International flights are resuming from June 4, and for Portugal mainland quarantine is no more required.

https://www.cntraveler.com/story/flights-to-portugal-from-the-us-will-resume-june-4 ([mirror 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20200606035458/https://www.cntraveler.com/story/flights-to-portugal-from-the-us-will-resume-june-4), [mirror 2](https://archive.vn/dCgeV)):

> As destinations all over the world continue to ease coronavirus-related restrictions, restaurants, resorts, and air routes are slowly reopening. On June 4, Portugal’s national airline, TAP Air Portugal, will resume its nonstop flight between Lisbon and Newark airport, following the completion of the country’s three-phase reopening strategy. On June 6, Portugal will formally allow E.U. nations, except Spain and Italy, to enter via air. Travelers to mainland Portugal will not be required to quarantine, but stricter measures are in place for those visiting the Azores and Madeira.

Obviously things can change in case of a second covid-19 wave.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Caveat: As you said, getting the straight scoop on this is not easy, and is rapidly changing.

As of July 2020:

- No tourism from United States
- Yes tourism from EU, Canada, and over a dozen other countries.

## Details

Portugal [had re-opened tourist (“non-essential”) travel](https://www.travelandleisure.com/travel-news/portugal-coronavirus-reopening-travel-bubble) from the US in May-June 2020, but that has been [stopped in July 2020](https://reopen.europa.eu/en).

Tourist (“non-essential”) travel from some countries other than the US has resumed:

- Algeria, Australia, Canada, Georgia, Japan, Montenegro, Morocco, New Zealand, Rwanda, Serbia, South Korea, Thailand, Tunisia, Uruguay, China, subject to confirmation of reciprocity.
- EU Member States and from countries that are parties to the [Schengen Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Agreement).

If you are a US citizen, see:

- US State Department [page for travel to Portugal](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Portugal.html)
- [US Embassy & Consulate in Portugal](https://pt.usembassy.gov/)
- Portugal’s [official tourism](https://www.visitportugal.com/en) web site
- European Union [website for reopening](https://reopen.europa.eu/en)

  - Specific [EU page for Portugal](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/PRT)

They say:

- US State Dept recommends against all international travel due to the global impact of COVID-19.
- ➥ As of 2020-07-08, all approved U.S. travelers to Portugal must present proof of a negative COVID-19 test conducted within 72 hours prior to boarding.  Failure to do so may result in refusal to board, refusal of entry or mandatory testing at the cost of the passenger and quarantine upon arrival.
- The [US Embassy in Portugal says](https://pt.usembassy.gov/covid-19-information/)

  - The Government of Portugal currently prohibits non-essential (tourist) travel to Portugal by U.S. citizens. However, some airlines continue to sell tickets for travel between the United States and Portugal. Please confirm your eligibility to enter Portugal with the airline and review the airline’s policy on refunds before purchasing tickets.
  - Portuguese airports in Lisbon, Porto, Faro, Ponta Delgada, Funchal and Lajes implemented a body temperature measurement requirement upon arrival.
  - Portuguese authorities announced that foreign passengers arriving aboard ships and other vessels will not be allowed to disembark.
  - There continues to be a State of Calamity in Madeira with additional entry requirements.
  - The U.S. government does not anticipate arranging repatriation flights in Portugal

This is a fast-changing situation. I get the feeling that even these official web sites may not be up-to-date.